# How do I add a new row at the bottom of the grid? Kendo UI Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm attempting to add a new row when clicking on "Add New". Please take the example in: [Kendo UI for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-row-click/). Is there an option like Jquery with "createAt" or do we have to do some DOM manipulation? Please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can change some implementation down there, if you really need this to be done, it will add your row to the bottom.
On your **products.service.ts** change this line of code in  `save` method

```
this.data.splice(0, 0, product);
```

to

```
this.data.push(product);
```

and all will work as you wanted.

Comment: Funny enough, that's exactly what I did an hour before seeing this post. The part that threw me off was to use "sender.addRow", but I simply removed it from my code and used the "data.push" and it works well.